# UIScrollView and variable text size

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview

I'm creating an app with quite a lot of text. It will be of variable size, so I was wondering if there is a way to adapt my ScrollView to the size of the UILabel, not knowing in the IB what will be the number of lines of that label. I'm doing it from the IB, drag n dropping it, then I'm putting 4 elements inside : an image for the logo, a title, another image, and then the label.

My question is : how can I tell my ScrollView to adapt to the text ? With constraints ? In the code ? I'm sooooo lost with that scrolling thing…

I think I need a very very good tutorial about autolayout…

Here's some screenshots of my project 
[The project on simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Q9l.png)
[The layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMJkT.png)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the constraints to your label so that it will always have the same spacing to the scroll view. Also, you will have to set your labels lines to 0.

Don't press `Add Missing Constraints` because it will probably set your height and you don't want that to happen. Use the `Pin` button to set the spacing to nearest neighbor.

These are the buttons you will have to use, they are bottom right.
[image: Buttons]

First of all, press the one in the right and select All Views > Clear Constraints.

Then, select your label in the storyboard and press the button with a square `Pin`, here you will have to select everything until you have something like this with different values... Also click in the red lines so that you get a continuous red line. Don't check any of the boxes you see.

[image]

After this, you have to do the same process for your Scroller.

It should be enough. I will also need to know where your scroller is.

If you have anything else in your view, do the same.

Comment: Oh boy I'm so lost… It doesn't work, do you think you'll be so kind to send me an example ? So I can check what's going on… Sorry but I'm really getting crazy on this I don't understand why!

Comment: Sure, I went through that and it is pretty annoying. I would be so glad if you accepted my answer (tick). I am editing my answer in a sec.

Comment: Thanks a loooooooot I'm losing my sanity here!

Comment: I understand you perfectly, it took me a while to figure it out. When you get it, it will be pretty easy. Feel free to ask anything else

Comment: This is also a good tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

Comment: I'll wait for your news. It will be helpful to see a screenshot of your view

Comment: I'll try tomorrow ! Thanks a lot anyway !

Comment: Erk. So in fact I knew the principle of constraints (I have a CSS background), but I don't know why, here I can't figure why it's not working. I followed that video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OwdGD1fl4uU which is pretty much what I'm looking for, but he's chosing 1200 for the height of his view, and I want it to be constraint to the textlabel height. 

Do you really have to put another view in the scrollable view? Why is that?

Could you show me an exemple file ? So I can study the constraints in the size inspector ? That would be amazing…

Comment: Update your question with a screenshot ofyour view so that I can figure out what I have to do @petaire

Comment: Done ! I've also added a link for the file project.